# Updating Kotlin Room Database automatically from the API without need for user input

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

How can I update Room Database automatically, when changes are made from an API?

This portion of the code works to update, however, changes are only made when I filter my list of items.  I would like for it to be done automatically without any user input.

*To add, I'm just a hobbyist and learning what I can, but all the tutorials and projects I've found are more intimidating for me, so I may not be explaining this correctly or accurately.*

The app I'm working on has been a big hit across the U.S Air Force, so I'm doing my best to create a great product and this has been a frequently requested item.

`    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PubsViewHolder, position: Int) {
val publication = pubsListFiltered[position]

```
    holder.apply {
        pubNumber.text = publication.Number
        pubTitle.text = publication.Title
        pubCertDate.text = "Certified Current: ${publication.getCertDate()}"
        pubRescindOrg.text = "Rescind Org: ${publication.RescindOrg}"

        // Last Action category hardcoded for brevity
        val actionText = when (publication.LastAction) {
            "GM" -> ct.getString(R.string.guidance_memorandum)
            "AC" -> ct.getString(R.string.ac)
            "IC" -> ct.getString(R.string.interim_change)
            "UpdateContact" -> ct.getString(R.string.update_contact)
            "Rewrite" -> ct.getString(R.string.rewrite)
            "Transfer" -> ct.getString(R.string.transfer)
            "Correction" -> ct.getString(R.string.correction)
            "CertifiedCurrent" -> ct.getString(R.string.certified_current)
            else -> ct.getString(R.string.unknown_action)
        }
        pubLastAction.text = actionText

        // Clipboard Service
        val clipboard: ClipboardManager =
            ct.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager

        val fEntity = FavoriteEntity().apply {
            id = publication.PubID
            Number = publication.Number
            Title = publication.Title
            DocumentUrl = publication.DocumentUrl
        }

        if (favoriteDAO?.titleExists(publication.Number.toString()) == 1) {
            // Does exist, updates
            favoriteDAO.update(fEntity)
        }

        // Popup Menu
        buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener {
            // Setting Theme
            // Create Pop-up Menu
            val wrapper: Context = ContextThemeWrapper(ct, R.style.AppTheme)
            val popup = PopupMenu(wrapper, buttonViewOption)

            // Inflates Menu
            popup.inflate(R.menu.popup_main)

            // Clicklistener
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
                when (item.itemId) {
                    // Bookmark
                    R.id.mSave -> {
                        if (favoriteDAO?.titleExists(publication.Number.toString()) == 0) {
                            favoriteDAO.addData(fEntity)
                            showSuccessToast("${publication.Number}: added to database!")
                        } else {
                            favoriteDAO?.update(fEntity)
                            showInfoToast("${publication.Number}: updated!")
                        }
                    }

                    // Copy AFI URL
                    R.id.mCopyURL -> {
                        val clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Pub!", publication.DocumentUrl)
                        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
                        showInfoToast("Saved URL to clipboard")
                    }

                    // Share AFI by URL
                    R.id.mShare -> {
                        val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
                            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, publication.DocumentUrl)
                            type = "text/plain"
                        }

                        val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
                        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                        startActivity(ct, shareIntent, null)
                    }

                    // Download file to device
                    R.id.mDownload -> {
                        /**
                         ** fileDir: Standard directory in which to place documents that have been created by the user.
                         ** subPath: Creates sub-folder that the app will download to
                         ** request: parses url of the selected AFI/Publication
                         */
                        val manager =
                            ct.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager

                        val fileDir = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS
                        val subPath = "/AFIExplorer// ${publication.Title}"
                        val request =
                            DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(publication.DocumentUrl))

                        request.setTitle(publication.Number)
                        request.setDescription(publication.Title)
                        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                            fileDir,
                            "$subPath.pdf"
                        )
                        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                        info(
                            ct,
                            publication.Number + " downloaded to: " + fileDir + "/AFIExplorer/",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                            true
                        ).show()

                        // Deprecated
                        manager.enqueue(request)
                    }
                }
                false
            }
            popup.show()
        }
    }
}`
```

Current code layout allows for updating, but only when filtering my list again, does the item change/update accordingly.  I'd like to update without the extra user input.

Comment: You could do an auto save/update by using the OnTextChanged(). Look into OnTextChanged() in kotlin. What happens is if a character is added to the edit text and after a little pause it saves/updates